# Enable Cacti to monitor JMX

Tags: jmx, cacti

How do I configure CACTI to monitor values comming from JMX?

Answer (score 3):

http://forums.cacti.net/post-197459.html has a nice tutorial for how to setup Cacti in order to use [jmx4perl](http://www.jmx4perl.org) for monitoring JMX values. A future version of jmx4perl might even include some cacti scripts out of the box.